# css id in php echo not working

Tags: php, css, styles, echo

I can't seem to get the class id's that I'm assigning within a php echo to be recognized by CSS. Here is the code. It seems like I am missing something simple but I can't seem to figure out or see what it is.

```
echo "<table class='item'>
                    <tr>
                        <td id='name'><h3>" . $name . "</h3></td>
                        <td id='itemdescription'>" . $description . "</td>
                        <td id='imagelocaiton'><img src='" . $location . "'id='image'></td>
                        <td id='price'>" . $price . "</td>";
```

And associated CSS:

```
#image {
width: 300px;
height: auto;
}

#itemdescription {
color: red;
}
```

Thank you!

EDIT: This is the output HTML from inspect element. I suppose I should have mentioned this id being modified using a while loop drawing the table information from a MySQL database. I just noticed that my CSS seems to work using google chrome but not in Safari...

```
<html><head>
    <title>For Sale</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<style type="text/css"></style></head>
<body>
    <div class="item_list">

        <table class="item">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td id="name"><h3>had</h3></td>
                        <td id="itemdescription">adfafdsaf</td>
                        <td id="imagelocaiton"><img src="images/simple.gif" id="image"></td>
                        <td id="price">$0</td></tr></tbody></table><table class="item">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td id="name"><h3>Idkd</h3></td>
                        <td id="itemdescription">adfaf</td>
                        <td id="imagelocaiton"><img src="images/Airplane Logo.jpg" id="image"></td>
                        <td id="price">$0</td></tr></tbody></table><table class="item">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td id="name"><h3>adfag</h3></td>
                        <td id="itemdescription">adfaf</td>
                        <td id="imagelocaiton"><img src="images/Jason.jpeg" id="image"></td>
                        <td id="price">$1313</td></tr></tbody></table><table class="item">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td id="name"><h3>afaf</h3></td>
                        <td id="itemdescription">adfafaf</td>
                        <td id="imagelocaiton"><img src="images/HDR1.jpg" id="image"></td>
                        <td id="price">$331</td>
```

Comment: I think you have missed item class.. in css

Comment: Could you post the html that the echo outputs? Or provide a url where we could look at it?

Comment: @LakshmiPrasanna The class shouldn't make a difference here, as jason is using ids.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responses. I can't post the page since this is all on localhost right now. The HTML output just appears like there is no CSS styling whatsoever. It also doesn't work if I use global styles on the <img> or <table> tags.

Comment: @LakshmiPrasanna Here's a fiddle for what the output should look like: http://jsfiddle.net/jameslafferty/9QDBR/

Comment: jason, if you could post the view source of the page you're producing, that might help.

Comment: alright, I have posted it above by edited my post

Comment: Well, I wasn't able to get it to work in Safari but I cleared history and cookies and it is now displaying as it should. Thanks for the help ... I wonder why it was doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, you have make a small change in image tag :

```
<td id='imagelocaiton'><img src='" . $location . "'id='image'></td>
try make minor correction
<td id='imagelocaiton'><img src='" . $location . "' id='image'></td>
```

Its working fine but assurance of the $location have correct path and image filename with extension. I got the Description in red color and Image in shown as per given css.

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all you written wrong code. There can not be more than one id on whole page.

Differentiate between class & id : http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

And try again with single id.